# Service Worker not working with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) for generating a react.js project. It automatically implements a service-worker for progressive web app funtionality if a production build was made by using the command `npm run build`.

Two weeks ago everything worked fine and I was able to cache all files with the generated service-worker. But since today I always get errors:

On Chrome: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request for http://localhost:5000/index.html?_sw-precache=aee80fca0f83208cc4d82ae2ccfda3c1 returned a response with status 301 at service-worker.js:1`.

On Firefox: `Service worker event waitUntil() was passed a promise that rejected with 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'.`

I have absolutely not idea why the error occurs.

Even if I create a new app and don't touch any of the generated files, the error shows up in the browsers console.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `npx create-react-app my-app`
2. `cd my-app`
3. `npm run build`
4. `serve -s  build`
5. `open app in browser`

I tested it on two separate machines but get the same result. Any help is very appreciated.

Edit:

Console output after running `npm run build`:

`C:PATH-TO-PROJECT>npm run build`

`> frontend@0.1.0 build C:\xampp\htdocs\gitlab\BA\App-PWA-progetraenke.app\frontend`
`> react-scripts build`

`Creating an optimized production build...`
`Compiled successfully.`

`File sizes after gzip:`

`164.04 KB  build\static\js\main.d2519277.js`
  `781 B      build\static\css\main.77261875.css`

`The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.`
`You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.`
`For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:`

`"homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",`

`The build folder is ready to be deployed.`
`You may serve it with a static server:`

`serve -s build`

`Find out more about deployment here:`

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Comment: It will be help in understanding problem if you can paste entire output of executing mom run build from the console.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a VueJS app I created by using the PWA template of Vue. What did the trick for me was updating to the latest version of vue-cli and serve.

Updating to the latest serve version (8.1.4) probably solved my problem.

Comment: I already tried that. Today I started the program again and somehow it works now. I really don't know what caused the issue.